# How to make the dvips -Pcmz command from lshort.pdf work on a Debian system?

Tags: dvips, debian

I am learning to use LaTeX from lshort.pdf.

I am using a Debian 8.3 system with `texlive` package installed.

I have this code in foo.tex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Small is beautiful.
\end{document}
```

I compiled it to a DVI file with this command.

```
latex foo.tex
```

Then I learnt this in the book in section 1.5.

> Convert the dvi file to PostScript for printing or viewing with GhostScript.
>
> ```
> dvips -Pcmz foo.dvi -o foo.ps
> ```

But when I try this, I get this error.

```
$ dvips -Pcmz foo.dvi -o foo.ps
dvips: warning: no config file for `cmz'
This is dvips(k) 5.994 Copyright 2014 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
dvips: DVI file can't be opened: foo.dvi: No such file or directory
```

I read the man page for `dvips` command. It mentions this.

```
-P printername
       Sets  up  the  output  for the appropriate printer.  This is implemented by reading in config.printername , which can then set the output pipe (as in, !lpr -Pprintername as
       well as the font paths and any other config.ps defaults for that printer only.  Note that config.ps is read before  config.printername  In  addition,  another  file  called
       ~/.dvipsrc  is  searched  for immediately after config.ps; this file is intended for user defaults.  If no -P command is given, the environment variable PRINTER is checked.
       If that variable exists, and a corresponding configuration file exists, that configuration file is read in.
```

But I don't understand where `config.printername` is supposed to be located and why it is missing from my system?

Comment: You seem to be learning a rather 'traditional' route: most people go for `pdflatex` for direct PDF production, and if using `dvips` just do `dvips foo`

Comment: Well, the documentation states it: `-Pcmz` is a special setup for a printer model cmz (whatever this might be)

Comment: I think that `-Pcmz` has become obsolete several years ago. Just doing `dvips foo.dvi -o` is sufficient. Also `dvipdf` is not the most fashionable device: `ps2pdf` is much better. That part of `lshort` should be thoroughly revised.